# Android: Updating a LinearLayout position after animation is complete

Tags: android, animation

Any help with the following problem would be greatly appreciated. I know what I need to do and I have checked the Developer docs, but the exact syntax I need to use eludes me (I'm a noob).

Here's what I'm doing. I have a translate.xml file in res/anim that works fine. It looks like this:

```
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
   android:fromXDelta="0%" 
   android:toXDelta="0%" 
   android:fromYDelta="0%" 
   android:toYDelta="10%" 
   android:repeatCount="0" 
   android:duration="1000" 
   android:fillEnabled="true" 
   android:fillAfter="true"/>
```

I'm executing my code like this:

```
    l = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);
    a = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.translate);
    a.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation anim){};
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation anim){};
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation anim){
            //l.setLayoutParams(params);
        };
    });
l.startAnimation(a);
```

When the animation is done I would like the LinearLayout it animated to move to it's new position (where the animation moved it to). The reason for this is the LinearLayout contains several form elements the user can interact with.

This is a real simple animation for a fairly simple project. It simply moves the element about 30 pixels down the screen. I wouldn't ask for help except I've been struggling with this for several hours now. I know I need to update the LinearLayout's parameters on the end of the animation, but how exactly? I've read of several different ways and they're all a bit confusing.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a new `AnimationListener`, try implementing the `AnimationListener` interface to your current (or a new) class.  Then just override the `onAnimationEnd()` method.

Example:

```
public class ThisClass implements AnimationListener {

      private otherMethod() {
          l.getAnimation().setAnimationListener(this);
      }

      public void onAnimationStart(Animation anim){};
      public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation anim){};
      public void onAnimationEnd(Animation anim){
          l.setLayoutParams(params);
      };
```

}

Comment: That would seem to make sense. I extended the calss with the AnimationListener like you instructed and added the neccessary listener methods. Except that the "params" cannot be resolved to a variable in the onAnimationEnd method. What did you mean by that? What would params be referencing?

Comment: And l.getAnimation().setAnimationListener(this); crashes my application :-(

Comment: you need to create a new LayoutParams variable, or else create one public to the class.  Why does it crash (what did logcat say)?

Comment: a.setAnimationListener(this);

Setting the LayoutParams and passing in the values is what I'm confused about. I don't know how to target the the new position to set my LinearLayout to, or if that is even what I should be doing.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got a way to work around,the right way to do this is **`setFillAfter(true)`**,

if you want to define your animation in xml then you should do some thing like this

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
     android:fillAfter="true">

    <translate 
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="-100%"
        android:duration="1000"/>

</set>
```

you can see that i have defined **`filterAfter="true"`** in the `set` tag,if you try to define it in `translate` tag it won't work,might be a **bug** in the framework!!

and then in the Code

```
Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_out);
someView.startAnimation(anim);
```

**OR**

```
TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(-90, 150, 0, 0);

            animation.setFillAfter(true);

            animation.setDuration(1800);

            someView.startAnimation(animation);
```

then it will surely work!!

Now this is a bit tricky it seems like the view is actually move to the new position but actually the pixels of the view are moved,i.e your view is actually at its initial position but not visible,you can test it if have you some button or clickable view in your view(in my case in layout),to fix that you have to manually move your view/layout to the new position

```
public TranslateAnimation (float fromXDelta, float toXDelta, float fromYDelta, float toYDelta)

new TranslateAnimation(-90, 150, 0, 0);
```

now as we can see that our animation will starts from -90 x-axis to 150 x-axis

so what we do is set

```
someView.setAnimationListener(this);
```

and in

```
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation)
{
   someView.layout(150, 0, someView.getWidth() + 150, someView.getHeight());
}
```

now let me explain `public void layout (int left, int top, int right, int botton)`

it moves your layout to new position first argument define the left,which we is **150**,because translate animation has animated our view to **150 x-axis**, **top is 0** because we haven't animated y-axis,now in right we have done `someView.getWidth() + 150` basically we get the width of our view and added **150** because we our left is now move to **150 x-axis** to make the view width to its originall one, and bottom is equals to the height of our view.

I hope you people now understood the concept of translating, and still you have any questions you can ask right away in comment section,i feel pleasure to help :)

**EDIT** Don't use `layout()` method as it can be called by the framework when ever view is invalidated and your changes won't presist, use `LayoutParams` to set your layout parameters according to your requirement